# Foreignkey field get '[object object]' value when editRow with original field value is null

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an issue that I use a dropdown list for my foreignkey field like demo : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html

The difference is that the foreignkey field in my model which can be null some time if it is not related to anyone else. Then the issue for me is when I try to editRow with this foreignkey field's original value is null,  and I want to change to another value, this field will always get the value '[object object]'. I don't know why.

See the floor field in the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var template = kendo.template($("#detail_template").html());

        function show_menu_details(menuObj) {
            var tg = $("#details");
            tg.fadeOut(function(){
                tg.html(template(menuObj));
                tw = tg.find(".k-window");


                tw.css({width:tg.innerWidth()-30, height:tg.innerHeight()-55, "margin-top": 20, "margin-left":15});
            });
            tg.fadeIn();
        }

        $("#horizontal").kendoSplitter({
            panes: [{collapsible: true, size: "180px"},
                    { collapsible: true} ],
            height: 690
        });

        function onChange(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            selectedObj = this.dataSource.getByUid(this.select().data('uid'))
            //console.log(selectedObj);//(this.dataSource.data());
            show_menu_details(selectedObj);
        }

        var statuses = [
            {value:'', text:'--'},
            {value:'Available', text:'Available'},
            {value:'Locked', text:'Locked'},
            {value:'Reserved', text:'Reserved'},
            {value:'Occupied', text:'Occupied'}];
        var floors = new Array();
        floors[0]={text:'--',value:''};
        _DS_Floor.fetch(function(data){
            $.each(data.items,function(index,obj){
                floors[index+1] = {text: obj.name, value: obj.id};
            });

            var grid = $("#list").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: _DS_Room,
                selectable: "row",
                filterable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                pageable: {refresh:true},
                editable: {mode:"popup",confirmation:"Sure to delete?"},
                height: 688,
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                toolbar: kendo.template($("#toolbar_template").html()), 
                columns: [//{field:'id',title:' ',width:40,template: '<input type="checkbox" id="#= id #" />'},
                          {field:'name',title:'Name'},
                          {field:'floor',title:'Floor',values:floors},
                          {field:'position',title:'Position'},
                          {field:'status',title:'Status',width:80,values:statuses}],//_Columns_Menu,//{ command: ['edit','destroy'], title: "", width: "200px" }
                //change: onChange
            });

            grid.find("#btn-add").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                grid.data("kendoGrid").addRow();
            });

            grid.find("#btn-save").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                grid.data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();//editRow(grid.data("kendoGrid").select());
            });

            grid.find("#btn-remove").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                grid.data("kendoGrid").removeRow(grid.data("kendoGrid").select());
            });

            grid.find("#btn-cancel").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                grid.data("kendoGrid").cancelChanges();//removeRow(grid.data("kendoGrid").select());
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable values are not supported. [Here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/foreignkey-field-get-object-object-value-when-editrow-with-original-field-value-is-null.aspx) is question from the KendoUI forums to which Vladimir Iliev provided explanation and solution. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2017? It seems kind of crazy that null isn't supported, and the solution is a hack.